# Disconnect MutationObserver After observing All Changes & Call Next Function

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have a list of products on a page.
When I filter or sort products, I want my mutationobserver to connect.
When the mutationobserver finishes returning all the changes it observed, then and only then do I want to disconnect so that I can call my next function.

```
var optModify = new MutationObserver(entries => {
  console.log(entries);
if(observer === complete){
   nextFunction()
}
});

var optTarget = document.querySelector('.mainContainer')

optModify.observe(optTarget, {
    attributes: !0,
    childList: !0,
    characterData: !0,
    subtree: !0
});
```

The mutationobserver is observing as expected, I just don't know how to tell it to stop so that I can run my next function and insert new content to the page (which I don't want it to observe)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use `observer.disconnect();` when the moment is right. For example, after observed the expected change

```js
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  /*
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
    } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
      console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
    }
  }
  */

  console.log("something changed. won't observe again");


  // Later, you can stop observing
  observer.disconnect();
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

```html
<div id="some-id" contenteditable tabindex="0">edit me, press [Enter] to append div</div>
```

Comment: this makes sense, but in this example, I am just observing anything in the list changing (e.g. children, attributes, etc).  As such, when I log what's changing in the console, depending on the user action, sometimes 2 mutations will be output, other times 13, I just want to know when all the mutations have been observed so I know nothing else is going to change.  Do I have to key off of something specific or can I just wait for the mutations to finish?

Comment: Depending on your case it's worth testing, but I think it fires once all mutations in response to one "action". Not sure.